# Transition from Delaunay triangulation to Voronoi diagram

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, voronoi-diagrams

In mathematics and computational geometry, a Delaunay triangulation for a given set P of discrete points in a plane is a triangulation DT(P) such that no point in P is inside the circumcircle of any triangle in DT(P).

A Voronoi diagram is a kind of tesselation that divided the medium into polygons in 2D and polyhedrons in 3D.

I have Delaunay triangulation of a three-dimensional space. For the transition from Delaunay to Voronoi, firstly center of circumsphere of  Delaunay tetrahedron is found (vertice) then edges linked to this center are determined. Founded edges are formed polyhedron faces.

I want to know: is there any algorithm that finds polyhedron faces from edges?

I will appreciate any comments that give me a little help and forgive me for writing shortcomings.

Comment: "finds polyhedron faces from edges" - can you [edit] the question to clarify in what context?  Do you mean, from the edges of a 3D Delaunay triangulation?

Comment: @D.W. I really do not know the meaning of "what context?". Your next question is clear but I will improve it.